# Can not add Android Native Module to React Native project

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-native-module, react-native-modules

I have a task where I need to add a Native functionality to the React Native project for Android devices.

I have followed this [tutorial][1], which is pretty straight-forward. But unfortunately, I still can not access my Native functionality from JS layer.

Here's how my code looks like.

`SimpleTestModule.java`:

```
package com.reactnativesampleapp;

import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class SimpleTestModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    SimpleTestModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "SimpleTestModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void simplePublicMethod() {
        Log.d("SimpleTestModule", "Some cool log!");
    }
}
```

`SimpleTestPackage.java`:

```
package com.reactnativesampleapp;

import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SimpleTestPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
            ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new SimpleTestModule(reactContext));
        Log.d("SimpleTestPackage", "Log just to check if this code gets executed");

        return modules;
    }
}
```

And finally, Here's my `MainApplication.java`:

```
package com.reactnativesampleapp;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.makeupreactnativesampleapp.generated.BasePackageList;

import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactAdapterPackage;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ModuleRegistryAdapter;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactModuleRegistryProvider;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.Package;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.SingletonModule;
import expo.modules.constants.ConstantsPackage;
import expo.modules.permissions.PermissionsPackage;
import expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemPackage;
import expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  private final ReactModuleRegistryProvider mModuleRegistryProvider = new ReactModuleRegistryProvider(
    new BasePackageList().getPackageList()
  );

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      Log.d("Eugene", "getPackages!");
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
      packages.add(new SimpleTestPackage());
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }

    @Override
    protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
      return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage();
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getJSBundleFile() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getJSBundleFile();
      } else {
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getLaunchAssetFile();
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getBundleAssetName() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getBundleAssetName();
      } else {
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getBundleAssetName();
      }
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      UpdatesController.initialize(this);
    }

    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.makeupreactnativesampleapp.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here's a JS file where I use my Native module:

```
import React from 'react';

import { 
  StyleSheet, 
  SafeAreaView, 
  NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { SimpleTestModule } = NativeModules;

export default function App() {

  SimpleTestModule.simplePublicMethod();
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
  });
```

After adding everything, I clean Android project via `./gradlew clean` and run `npm run android`

Few notes:

1. I have put a log into my Package class just to see if it even gets executed. Unfortunately, log never appeared so I guess it doesn't get executed
2. When I run `npm run android`, compilation is successful, but `.apk` is failing to launch on the device automatically. Can that be a signal that I have serious issues in my setup?

Here's a log at the end of `npm run android` execution:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 49s
508 actionable tasks: 508 executed
info Connecting to the development server...
warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT
info Starting the app...
error Failed to start the app. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: spawnSync adb ENOENT
    at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1086:20)

  [1]: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android
```

3. When I run Android app on the device through `Expo`, I have such logs when the app gets launched:

`    Error: Unable to resolve module ./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4 from /Users/superyevhen/Documents/Work/Resources/releases/MakeupReactNativeSampleApp/.:

```
None of these files exist:
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4(.native|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json)
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4/index(.native|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/superyevhen/Documents/Work/Resources/releases/MakeupReactNativeSampleApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:168:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/superyevhen/Documents/Work/Resources/releases/MakeupReactNativeSampleApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:353:43)
    at /Users/superyevhen/Documents/Work/Resources/releases/MakeupReactNativeSampleApp/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:271:42
    at /Users/superyevhen/Documents/Work/Resources/releases/MakeupReactNativeSampleApp/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1097:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/superyevhen/Documents/Work/Resources/releases/MakeupReactNativeSampleApp/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:99:24)
    at _next (/Users/superyevhen/Documents/Work/Resources/releases/MakeupReactNativeSampleApp/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:119:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Error: Unable to resolve module ./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4 from /Users/superyevhen/Documents/Work/Resources/releases/MakeupReactNativeSampleApp/.:`
```

This message repeats multiple times (7 times actually), but the app is working. I still can modify JS layer successfully and see changes, but my native modules are still not present. Can that be a root cause of an issue?

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried to be as precise as possible but if you need any additional info in order to share an expertise, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There seems a problem with your `MainApplication.java`. I tried with your file it was having some undefined params.

Try this if it works for you.

```
package com.reactnativesampleapp;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          packages.add(new SimpleTestPackage());
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.reactnativesampleapp.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Rohit! Thank you for your response. I have just tried to use `MainApplication` you have provided but I still get an issue "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'SimpleTestModule.simplePublicMethod')

Comment: @EugeneAlexeev were you able to solve this issue?